# VB.NET 2015 - Close and Refresh a form using another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have three (3) form namely Form1, Form2 and Form3 with button.

Form1 is my main form, window state as MAXIMIZED and form border style as NONE.

```
My code from Form1 inside a button click event
   Dim form2 As New Form2
   form2.show()
```

Form2 is a pup-up form that displays some details. Window state as NORMAL and form border style as FIXED. It is opened using a button in Form1.

```
My code from Form2 inside a button click event
   Dim form3 As New Form3
   form3.showdialog()
```

Form3 is another pop-up form but is opened using showdialog(). This form hosts some input. When hitting a button in Form3, it must close Form2 and refresh Form1. Window state as NORMAL and form border style as NONE (hiding X to close the form, it will only use the button to close the form)

```
My code from Form3 inside a button click event
   me.hide()
   Dim form2 As New Form2
   form2.hide() '<--- not working
   Dim form1 As New Form1
   form1.refresh()  '<--- not working
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in Form1, wire up the Form2Closed() event of your Form2 instance and Refresh() from in there:

```
' ... in Form1 ...

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form2 As New Form2
    AddHandler form2.FormClosed, AddressOf form2_FormClosed
    form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

In Form2, you'd simply do:

```
' ... in Form2 ...

Dim form3 As New Form3
form3.ShowDialog() ' code stops here until form3 is dismissed
Me.Close()
```

Comment: I cant sir, Form2 can be open twice. Form2 opens only using Form1 Button.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in making the Form2 close using a Button in Form3

Inside the Form3, in the Button click event

```
Me.Close()

Dim form2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2)().FirstOrDefault()
If form2 IsNot Nothing Then
    form2.Close()
End If

Dim form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form1)().FirstOrDefault()
If form1 IsNot Nothing Then
    form1.Refresh()
End If
```

I think the form3.Refresh is working but it is not what I need. I want to call the Form1_Load load event in the Form1.
Anyone know how is it done?

Comment: Why are you asking a question in an answer?  I think you need to SO works.

Answer (score 0):

You say that those lines of code are not working but they are working.  They are doing exactly what they are supposed to do.  Take the first example:

```
Dim form2 As New Form2
form2.hide()
```

That code says "create a new `Form2` object and hide it".  Is that NEW `Form2` shown?  No it's not, so it's working.  Your expectation seems to be that telling that NEW `Form2` object to be hidden is magically going to hide the EXISTING `Form2` object.  It's not.  If you want to hide that EXISTING `Form2` object then you have to call `Hide` on that object, not on a new one.

Comment: Using a Button in Form3 must close the Form2 and refresh the From1

Comment: Then you need to call a method on THAT `Form2` object and not a new one.  That said, why would `Form3` be closing `Form2` at all when `Form3` is a modal dialogue opened by `Form2`?  To be frank, your whole design sounds screwy and your code really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: would be better if you posts the code? its the code that we all speak and understand. I cant understand mush english. sorry

Comment: I can't really post code to do what you want because what you want appears to makes no sense.  Let me see if I can decipher it. `Form1` opens `Form2` and `Form2` opens `Form3`. The user enters something into `Form3` and then closes `Form3`, at which point `Form2` closes and a change is made in `Form1`.  Is that right?  If so then the real problem is that you're doing things in the wrong place. What should be happening is `Form3` closes itself, `Form2` closes itself and `Form1` updates itself. If you can confirm the actual aim then I can post a code example of that.

Comment: Even I cannot posts all the codes I have. Because I have my own reasons why Im doing it. I am asking how is it done, not if im doing correct or wrong in my way of designing my own system. Again, I have my own reasons why I want to CLOSE the Form2 and REFRESH or CALL THE LOAD in the Form1 using a BUTTON in Form3. PS: CLOSING the Form2 using a BUTTON in Form3 is now working well. I got the code from this site as well. A guy whos willing to help and show the code. And who dont discriminate others work. Thanks but no thanks. Good luck sir. #noSense

Comment: Gee, sorry for thinking you might want to write code that wasn't garbage. I'll leave you to it.